# iOS how to get lat long from below string?

Tags: ios, string, cocoa, substring

I have a string and I want only two strings from that whole string. how to accomplish this. My string is,

`<+19.25647589,+72.97356784> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 17/10/14 15:04:02 India Standard Time.`

and I want `19.25647589` & `72.97356784` in two different variables. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's far more elegant to use `NSScanner` when trying to parse such values out of a string.

Essentially, skip the `<` character, scan the number, skip the `,` character, scan the number. And that's it.

In your case:

```
NSString *input = @"<+19.25647589,+72.97356784> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 17/10/14 15:04:02 India Standard Time.";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];

double latitude;
double longitude;

[scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
[scanner scanString:@"," intoString:nil];
[scanner scanDouble:&longitude];

NSLog(@"latitude: %f, longitude: %f", latitude, longitude);
```